# can Tesseract OCR be extended or trainned?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm looking for a OCR library that allows me to read text in an image, but only text that is circled. I want to get some feedback on Tesseract OCR for this task. It looks powerful but complex. HOw would it be used here, can I be trained for something like this? or should have to be extended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Tesseract is [fully trainable](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3). And it just happens that it supports text in a circle also (pagesegmode 9). Give it a try.